# User references broken?

Tags: bug

User references (at sign, user name) seem to be broken today, at least in comments.

If I type an at-sign followed by some letters, I no longer get a suggestion for completion.

If I type the full user name regardless, it vanishes on posting.

I fully expect this posting will prove me wrong, such is Murphy's law.

Comment: I am going to type at-another-dave here: @another-dave.  There, I typed it.  No auto-complete suggestion. Will it appear?

Comment: It's not _broken_, it's just that it only appears under certain conditions.

Comment: what are the conditions?  This is the first time I recall it not appearing.

Comment: You need more than two users, including the post owner. Editors can be @pinged, but they don't show up in the autocomplete list.

Comment: @another-dave Now it works. Tada!

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - so it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need more than two users, including the post owner. Editors can be @pinged, but they don't show up in the autocomplete list.

This happens because, when there are only two users in a comment thread, the system automatically pings the other user; thus, you don't *need* to @ping them.